Unable to launch VSCode as secondary user with su on Debian 12
I'm using Debian 12 in a VirtualBox VM (host: Windows 11). I have a main user who can launch the IDE VSCode from the console by running code ., which opens VSCode with the current folder/pwd as the project directory.
I also have a secondary user on the Debian system who can log in, start their own session, open a console, and successfully use code . to launch VSCode.
However, when I log into Debian with the main user through the graphical interface, open a terminal, and switch to the secondary user using su - user2, I encounter an issue:
The command which code confirms that VSCode is installed and returns '/usr/bin/code'.
But running code . fails to launch VSCode.
I am unsure what I'm missing in this setup. Do you have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?
(addendum: or perhaps it's not an issue and it is just normal that you can't access graphical resources as a console user ?)
